# Find non-called methods in the project in Inteliji IDEA

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Is there some kind of plugin or keyboard shortcut to search for all non-called methods in IDEA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intellij does provide a way to inspect the code, You can explore it out[image]

You can enable the type of configuration you want and then do a code inspect.

as below
[image]

in summary you can see as per below image, declaration suggesting `never used method`.
[image]